# How to enable Inplace Editing for this code..so i need that value to update in Update.php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to enable Inplace Editing for this following code

View.php:

```html
<tr  class="tredit">                        
    <td contenteditable="true" class="td_edit">
        <input type="hidden"  class="edt" id="cnum<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" />
        <span class="text"   id="spnum<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
            <?php echo $row[1]; ?>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable="true" class="td_edit">
        <input type="hidden"  class="edt" id="cname<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>"   />
        <span class="text" id="spname<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
            <?php echo $row[2]; ?>
        </span>
    </td>
```

If the user click on the field it will lead to enable edit the content after the edited content will send to the update.php file..Then it will save the updated content to the database
**Update.php**

```
 <?php
 include('path.php');
 $cid=$_POST['id']; 
 $cnum=$_POST['chapternumber'];
 $cname=$_POST['chaptername']; 
        $dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database"); 
        $query =  "update CHAPTER set `CHAPTER_NUMBER`='".$cnum."',`CHAPTER_NAME`='".$cname."' WHERE ID=".$cid; 
        $dbh->exec($query);      
  ?>
```

So i need javascript or jquery code to do the above function.If any one come across these situation send me the solution..

Comment: Do you want to auto update the content of your database when you change values on the HTML page?

Comment: @DavidePastore Yes,i need to change the value in database once the user edit the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View.php:

```html
<tr  class="tredit" data-id="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">                       
    <td contenteditable="true" class="td_edit">
        <input type="hidden"  class="edt" id="cnum<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" />
        <span class="text"   id="spnum<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
            <?php echo $row[1]; ?>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable="true" class="td_edit">
        <input type="hidden"  class="edt" id="cname<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>"   />
        <span class="text" id="spname<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
            <?php echo $row[2]; ?>
        </span>
    </td>
<tr>
```

After in the same file:

```
$('.td_edit').blur(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  var id = parent.data('id');
  var spans = parent.find('span.text');
  var cnum = spans.eq(0).text();
  var cname = spans.eq(1).text();

  var dataToSend = {
    id: id,
    chapternumber: cnum,
    chaptername: cname
  };
  $.post( "Update.php", dataToSend, function( data ) {
    console.log("Check the result %o", data);
  });
});
```